# Would it be possible to use Highchart to make a graph with no charts, but only corresponding numbers?

Tags: highcharts

I have tried around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n8veguor/3/) with

```
    threshold
```

and

```
    softThreshold
```

But to no avail.
Here is an example of the desired result:
[image: An example of the desired result]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you define transparent `colors` :

```
colors:['rgba(0,0,0,0)'],
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8veguor/5/)

Comment: Than you. Would it be possible to decide where the number will be? (e.g. I would like to keep them always at the same place (e.g. in the middle of the vertical direction, similar to the example picture (part of the chart was clipped away)))

Comment: The datalabels position will depend of the values themself.

Comment: Would it be possible that the position would be independent of the values themselves?

Comment: Yes, you can use `SVGRenderer` to generate them: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer